# replace words in php from list

Tags: php

I have code like this :

(please open this link)

```
    <?php
function stop_words($dok){
        $dokumen_trim = trim($dok);
        $dokumen_trim = strtolower($dokumen_trim);
        $hilangg = array("yang","di","dan","itu","dengan","untuk","tidak","ini","dari","dalam","akan","pada","juga","saya","ke","karena","tersebut","bisa","ada","mereka","lebih","sudah","atau","saat","oleh");
            $dokumen_trim = str_replace("/\b".$hilangg."\b/i", "", $dokumen_trim);

    return $dokumen_trim;
}
?>
```

but, it doesn't work..please help me guys

Comment: hi actually your question is bit unclear... can you please let me know what is input and what output you want?

Comment: You're trying to use regex in `str_replace` for one, the regex equivalent is `preg_replace`. If the boundaries are required you will need to implode the array with pipes to a `preg_replace`, else just pass the array alone as the first param to `str_replace`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all you're using regex (`\b`) but use `str_replace` to replace where you should use `preg_replace`.

Second of all - you can't just paste an array in there. You need to make a regex group:

Thirdly, you're replacing with nothing. This includes your word boundaries as well (`I am yang.` would get turned into `I am` (without a dot/space).

```
<?php
    function stop_words($dok){
        $dokumen_trim = trim($dok);
        $dokumen_trim = strtolower($dokumen_trim);
        $hilangg = array("yang","di","dan","itu","dengan","untuk","tidak","ini","dari","dalam","akan","pada","juga","saya","ke","karena","tersebut","bisa","ada","mereka","lebih","sudah","atau","saat","oleh");

        $regex = "/(\b)" . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $hilangg, '/')) . "(\b)/i";

        $dokumen_trim = preg_replace($regex, "$1$2", $dokumen_trim);

        return $dokumen_trim;
    }
?>
```